# Twitter API V2, return the x-rate-limit-limit, x-rate-limit-remaining, x-rate-limit-reset

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

Hello fellow overflowers.

I'm new to Twitter API. I'm using python. I'm using Tweepy library. I have the elevated access of twitter API, and I'm trying to get the rate limit information of the 15 min window.

1. I want the amount of time left in the 15 min window.
2. I want to know how much requests I have left in the 15 min window
3. and the rate limit ceiling for the endpoint.

Reference of what I want in twitter docs :

- x-rate-limit-limit: the rate limit ceiling for that given endpoint.
- x-rate-limit-remaining: the number of requests left for the 15-minute
  window.
- x-rate-limit-reset: the remaining window before the rate limit
  resets, in UTC epoch seconds.

Twitter Docs :
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits#headers-and-codes

I did a bit of search but cannot find anything on how to do it.
I found this Github sample code from twitter but still nothing:
https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code

And also on Tweepy I couldn't find anything:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html

But I can see the amount of requests when I use the request live from twitter self, but it's only 180 requests per 15 min, so its using the User-rate-limit and not the application-rate-limit :

https://oauth-playground.glitch.me/?id=tweetsRecentSearch&params=%28%27query%21%27from%3ATwitterDev%27%7Ebody%21%27%27%7Epath%21%28%29%29_

Does anyone know how to do this ? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function *search_recent_tweets* from *tweepy.Client* returns an object with type *tweepy.client.Response*, which does not contain information regarding rate limits.
Unfortunately, this means you won't be able to get it using tweepy.

An alternative could be to make the request yourself with a code like this:

```
import requests

def bearer_oauth(r):
    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer}"
    return r

bearer = "your bearer token"

params = {"query": "your search"}
    
response = requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent", params=params, auth=bearer_oauth)
```

After running that code, you will find rate limit information on *response.headers*.

Comment: hi @nicolasmgl, thnx for your answer. I tried the code u posted, but I'm not receiving what I want in return. This is what I receive from the response.headers:  
'{'perf': 'XX', 'content-type': 'application/problem+json', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0', 'content-length': 'XX', 'x-transaction-id': 'XX', 'x-response-time': 'XX', 'x-connection-hash': 'XX', 'date': 'XX', 'server': 'XX'}'. 

This is the params that I set for testing and the other 2: 'params = {"x-rate-limit-remaining": "search"}'

But I do make a connection and receive an object. or maybe i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Could you share the full code you are executing? Redacting sensitive material like the bearer_token of course.

I tried my code again and I can see "x-rate-limit-limit: 450" in response.headers.
That's what you are looking for, right?

Comment: hi @nicolasmgl, your code works fine, I just realized that I was using the tweepy client bearer, because I have the bearer in another file and I called it once at the top of my code. now I changed it and everything works fine. thnx for the help.